# Cloud Dataflow job stuck in endless loop before starting(create is succeded)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Cloud Dataflow job that's stuck in the initiation phase, before running any application logic. I tested this by adding a log output statement inside inside the processElement step, but it's not appearing in the logs so it seems it's not being reached.

All I can see in the logs are the following messages, this which appears every minute:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness

And these which loop every few seconds:

VM is healthy? true.

http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:38335: EOF

Job is in state JOB_STATE_RUNNING, will check again in 30 seconds.

The job ID is 2015-10-05_04_05_33-3751772463116380333

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: This error means the SDK isn't being properly staged to GCS and downloaded to your VMs.

DataflowWorkerHarness is the main class that runs on the workers. Its part of the SDK. What command line options are you using to set the classpath and staged files? Are you letting the Dataflow SDK automatically determine the files? Are you running under, maven, ant or an IDE?

Comment: I have extracted the code as a jar file(by using the eclipse export option) and running the file by the command java -jar <jar file name> <arguments>

Comment: i will not have this issue when i am executing the code from IDE.

Comment: When building a jar from eclipse there are three different ways to package your code but only 2 of the ways are compatible with Dataflow. This is described in detail in the answer to this [SO question](http://goo.gl/l1XQhC). Are you using one of the compatible ways?   Have you tried running using mvn exec as described in the [wordcount example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example)?

Comment: I was extracting the jar by selecting the option Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR, but when i created the jar by selecting the option Extract required libraries into generated JAR found to be working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear things are working.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the main class DataflowWorkerHarness wasn't found in the jar staged to GCS and started on the workers.

When building a Jar in eclipse, the Jar needs to be built in a manner compatible with Dataflow. The accepted methods are described in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978566/detectclasspathresourcestostage-unable-to-convert-url)